# How to add directory and subdirectories at once to Git

Tags: git

I want to push a directory from my computer that contains subdirectories to GitHub at once.

My folders structure:

```
parent_folder
  |_ child_folder_1
  |_ child_folder_2
  |_ etc
```

When I `git init` to the parent folder and try to `git add .` I got the error:

```
warning: adding embedded git repository: Child_folder_1
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint:
hint:   git submodule add <url> Child_folder_1
hint:
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
hint: index with:
hint:
hint:   git rm --cached Child_folder_1
hint:
hint: See "git help submodule" for more information.
```

And it's not just happened to one child folder but all of the child folders. Does it happen because subdirectories contain git too? So how can I fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Git does not store *directories*.  Git stores *files*, or more precisely, Git stores *commits* (that then store files—see the picky distinctions below).  But in your case, the problem is that those files are *already in a different Git repository* and therefore Git won't add them to *this* repository.

> Does it happen because subdirectories contain git too?

More precisely again, it's because those subdirectories *are* Git repositories (sort of; see picky distinctions below).

> So how can I fix this?

You must make a decision, one that has a lot of far-reaching consequences, right now (before you really understand all the consequences):

- Do you want to use Git's *submodules*, or
- do you want to *remove the other repositories* so that you can store these files directly in *this* repository?

#### Picky distinctions you'll need to know

A Git *repository* is mostly a collection of *commits*.  We generally find the commits by *branch names*, although there are exceptions to this rule.  *Cloning* a repository copies all (or at least most) of that repository's commits, but *does not copy its branch names*.  Instead, our Git—our software, creating and filling in our repository, reads the other repository's *branch* names and changes those into *remote-tracking names*.

The repository proper therefore consists mostly of two databases (after this there are numerous auxiliary things added to make them more usable).  One, usually the largest, holds the commits—Git calls these *commit objects* sometimes—plus other internal Git objects that Git needs.  This object database is a simple [key-value store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database) in which the *keys* are *hash IDs:* big ugly strings of letters-and-digits, which are actually hexadecimal numbers that are the output of a cryptographic checksum function.  The other database holds *names:* branch names, tag names, remote-tracking names, and so on.  Each name holds *one* hash ID; branch names in particular hold *commit* hash IDs, and hence let us find those particular commits.

Each *commit* in turn holds two things:

- Each commit holds a *full snapshot of every file*.  These files are stored in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated form.  They're not ordinary files, and they have names that have embedded forward slashes, such as `path/to/file.ext`, even on Windows; they're case-sensitive, even if you're on a case-insensitive Windows or macOS system; and so on.
- Each commit also holds some *metadata:* information about that particular commit.  This includes the name and email address of the person who made the commit.  It includes several date-and-time stamps, which help make each commit be unique.  And, crucially for Git's internal operation, each commit holds a list of *previous* commit hash IDs.

The previous-commit list in most commits is exactly one entry long, so that each commit just remembers the raw hash ID of its (single) *parent* commit.  This forms the commits into backwards-pointing chains, where the *latest* commit—with some big ugly random-looking hash ID; let's call this `H`—*points to* some earlier commit:

```
            <-H
```

Let's call the previous commit—which also has some big ugly random-looking hash ID as its real name—`G` just so we can talk about it, and draw it in:

```
        <-G <-H
```

Commit `G`, being a commit, stores the hash ID of some even-earlier commit `F`, and so on:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Each commit also has a full snapshot of every file, albeit with de-duplication, so that if some file in `G` exactly matches the file in `H`, there's really only one copy of that file in the repository.  (Git does this with hashing and what it calls *blob objects*, but you don't normally need to care about that.)

By *comparing* the snapshot in `G` to that in `H`, Git can tell you which files are the same—probably most of them—and which ones are different.  The `git diff`, `git show`, and `git log -p` commands can all do this kind of comparison: they'll show the files that are different and, by default, a recipe that would change the left-side file into the right-side file.  So comparing `G` vs `H` tells you which files changed, and what happened *to* those files.  `H` still stores a full snapshot though: to find out what changed, Git has to find `G`.  It can do that *because* `H` *points to* `G`.

You can't *use* a commit directly, because it *is* read-only, and only Git can actually read one anyway.  You can't get any new work done either, because it's read-only.  To solve this problem, we don't actually work directly with a commit.  Instead, we use `git checkout` or `git switch` to *extract* a commit.  This:

- removes all the previously-extracted files from whichever commit we had out before, then
- extracts all the files from the commit we're moving *to*

and now we have *usable* copies of each file.  These usable copies go into what Git calls your *working tree*, or *work-tree* for short.

These work-tree files are the files you actually *see* and *work with*.  They are ordinary files, stored by your computer, in its ordinary fashion, and they therefore live in directories (some people prefer the term "folders" here; either one is fine).  **These files are not in Git.**  They may well have come *out of* Git, via `git checkout`, but now that they're out, they're not in Git any more.  Anything you do to or with them does not affect Git.

If you've modified these files, or removed some, or created new ones, you must eventually tell Git about this.  Git will copy the files back into what it calls its *index* or *staging area*.  There's a lot to know about this (and you can't skimp on that knowledge as it's crucial to understanding the concept of a *tracked* vs *untracked* file, and how `.gitignore` really works), but we won't cover that here, but you'll run `git add`, and then eventually `git commit`.  The commit verb will make a *new* commit from the files as they appear in Git's staging area, and then update the current *branch name* to record the new commit as the latest commit on this branch.

The *repository itself* is normally<sup>1</sup> kept in a `.git` directory (or folder) at the top level of the working tree.  That is, if your repository is in `/Users/you/work/repo2`, there is a `/Users/you/work/repo2/.git` that contains the *repository*, and then everything else in `/Users/you/work/repo2` are the files extracted from the *current commit* that you checked out earlier with `git checkout` or `git switch`.

---

<sup>1</sup>The adjective *normally* is here because submodules and added-work-trees and a few other special cases can result in a *file* named `.git`.  Git uses this trick whenever there's some compelling reason to *move* the `.git` directory *away* from the working tree.  Submodules need to do this for some otherwise ugly cases; see below.

---

#### Submodules

Git's submodules add a wrinkle atop this otherwise relatively simple picture.  A *submodule* is, to a large extent, just a repository that is contained within another repository.  That is, there's a `.git` directory (or file, as per footnote 1) in one of the sub-directories of the working tree of some Git repository.

If a Git repository is using a submodule, we call that Git repository a *superproject*.  Both the superproject and the submodule still have all the usual attributes of a Git repository: they have the repository proper in the `.git` directory (or path found in the `.git` file), and a working tree with a commit checked out.  But the superproject needs to contain something extra, as we'll see in a moment.

The submodule, meanwhile, is *controlled by the superproject*.  The submodule *is* still a repository-and-working-tree, so there are still commits and you check one out.  Except: normally *you* don't do the checking out.  You have the *superproject* do that.

Suppose you've cloned some Git repository **R**, and you just now check out the first commit you will ever use *in* **R**, named by branch `B`.  Along with the *files* that go with commit `B`, there's an instruction, stored in the commit for `B`, that says, in effect: *and now clone and use another Git repository*.  This *other* repository is **S**, the submodule.  **R** is now a *superproject*, by definition.

In order to clone **S**, Git needs:

- the URL of the repository to clone;
- a path name within the working tree for the checkout in **R**; and
- a commit hash ID to `git checkout --detach` *in* **S** once it's made repository **S**.

Git gets the path name from an entry called a *gitlink*, and gets the commit hash ID from this same gitlink.  The gitlink comes out of commit `B` and goes into the index / staging-area for **R**, and to clone **S**, Git looks up the gitlink's path in the file `.gitmodules` as found in commit `B`.  This file has the URL, so the superproject Git is able to run the right `git clone` command:

```
git clone <url-for-S> path/to/s
```

for instance, or in your case:

```
git clone <url> Child_folder_1
```

**For the submodule clone to work, there must be a `.gitmodules` file with the right information in it.**  The `git submodule` command is the one that builds and maintains this `.gitmodules` file.  Hence, to add `Child_folder_1` *as* a submodule, you must run:

```
git submodule add <repository-url> Child_folder_1
```

This takes care of creating or updating the `.gitmodules` file so that the cloning instructions will be there; the *`repository-url`* you supply here is the one that `git clone` will get later.

If you simply `git add Child_folder_1`, Git adds the *gitlink* half of the set of instructions that a later clone will need.  But this doesn't add the `.gitmodules` entries.  That's why you get this error message:

> ```
> warning: adding embedded git repository: Child_folder_1
> hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
> hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
> hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
> hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
> hint:
> hint:   git submodule add <url> Child_folder_1
> [snip]
> ```

This is telling you that you've incorrectly added the submodule.

#### Why do we need submodules?

We don't.

We do, however, need to understand that a Git repository is *not allowed to contain another Git repository*.  Git *will not* add a file or directory named `.git` (or `.Git`, or `.GIT`, or `.giT`, or any other similar spelling).  More precisely, `.git` with any upper or lower case mix is forbidden as a name component.  So if you *do* have a repository within a repository, `git add` will not add the *files* here.  Instead, it will add this thing that Git calls a *gitlink*, which will give you submodule-style behavior.  The rest of Git, including `git status`, will not complain about these files being untracked either (although it may mention the *submodule repository itself* in the status).

You can, if you like, *remove* the `.git` file or directory from each submodule's working tree.  If you do that, you have made this no longer *be* the working tree of the corresponding Git repository.  Instead, these files—which are *still* ordinary files in your computer's ordinary format—are now ordinary but *untracked* files in the working tree of the repository.  We can use the phrase *the* repository now, because there's just the one repository you're working with.  When you have submodules, you are working with two or more repositories, so every time someone says "the repository", you must stop and ask: "wait, *which* repository?"

But: **If you remove the submodule repository entirely, there are no commits in the submodule repository any more.**  There is no submodule repository, so there are no commits.  So the untracked files you have in *the* (top level) repository working tree are the *only copies* of those files that you have.  You have *thrown away* all the *other*, committed, copies of those files.

You can now add and commit the `Child_folder_1` files to the (single) repository that holds the current working directory, including the subdirectory `Child_folder_1`.  But you only get *this one version* of those files.  As a submodule, you get a *gitlink* that says: *check out commit _______ (fill in the blank with a hash ID) after cloning*, and the `git clone` copies *all* the commits from some other repository, so that you have many versions of each file.

When you do have a submodule, you can *update the instructions* in the superproject.  You can say: *check out commit _______ (fill in the blank with a different hash ID this time)*.  The `git submodule update` command will, when run in the superproject, switch to *that* commit.  The working tree files will match the other commit now.

You can even say to *remove* that submodule.  The `git submodule update` command will remove the working tree files entirely.  (To avoid removing the `.git` directory, the actual *repository* lives in the superproject `.git` directory somewhere, so that it's safe to remove that `.git` file.)

#### So, you must decide

Submodules are quite inconvenient—so much so that many call them "sob-modules", as they make their users cry.  But they do something you cannot do without them.  Do you want to do this thing?  Or, do you want the simpler operation where you discard all the history that was in the *other* Git repository and simply take *this one version of those files* into what would be a superproject, if you added the submodule as a submodule?

The fast-and-easy thing to do is to give up all that history.  If you don't need it today, and will not need it tomorrow, this gets you back to the case of a single Git repository, without the complexities of submodules.  You won't be the one calling them sob-modules tomorrow.  But if you *will* need it tomorrow, you might, in the future, sob about not using those sub-modules yesterday.

You now have as much information as I can give you to make this decision.  Either use `git submodule add` to make these into proper submodules, or remove the `.git` and add them as ordinary files.